# GWT - Loading screen onButtonClick

Tags: gwt, google-visualization

I'm trying to create a loading screen (in this case a PopUp Panel) everytime I click on a button and to hide the screen when the processing is done.

But the problem is that the loading screen never appears.

If I delete the line that hides the loading screen:

```
   //HIDES THE LOADING POPUP
closeLoadingFilter();
```

The loading screen appears but only until everything finished processing. (not inmediately after I click the button).

I think all the processing in the button handler must be completed before anything appears on the screen. So when the processing is complete the popup is hidden before it was ever showed on the screen.

How can I solve this problem. By the way there is no Async call in the processing, everything is in-memory processing and the drawing of google visualizations with the in-memory information

Thank you all

Here is the code:

```
buttonFilter.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {


                            //SHOWS THE LOADING POPUP

            showLoadingFilter();


                            //ALL THIS TAKES AROUND 4 SECONDS
                            //THERE IS NO ASYNC CALL
                            //EVERYTHING IS IN-MEMORY PROCESSING
                            //AND DRAWING OF GOOGLE VISUALIZATION


            listValues.clear();
            listFields.clear();
            CreateListFiltersSingle();
            GetFilterSingleOptions();
            RunFilter(dashboardProductos);
            DrawVisualizations2();


                            //HIDES THE LOADING POPUP
            closeLoadingFilter();

        }

    })


public void showLoadingFilter() {

    popupFilterLoading.clear();

    popupFilterLoading.add(new Label("Please wait"));

    popupFilterLoading.setGlassEnabled(true); 

    popupFilterLoading.center(); 

    isFilterLoading = true;

    popupFilterLoading.show();

}

public void closeLoadingFilter() {
    if (isFilterLoading) {

        popupFilterLoading.hide();
        isFilterLoading = false;

    }

}
```

Comment: You don't need to call show, center already calls it.

Comment: A little weird what happens. Can you try to run the drawing code and the close loading in a scheduled deferred command?

Comment: Are some auf the methods you call before you call the     closeLoadingFilter();
 methods from the server (async) ?

Comment: Yes already tried the Scheduled , and no async methods are executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call methods asynchronously using a [scheduler](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html). The code below might solve your problem.

```
submit.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
          public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
              showLoadingFilter();
              // Waits for the loading pop-up to be displayed before starting anything
              Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
                @Override
                public void execute() {
                  listValues.clear();
                  listFields.clear();
                  CreateListFiltersSingle();
                  GetFilterSingleOptions();
                  RunFilter(dashboardProductos);
                  DrawVisualizations2();
                  closeLoadingFilter();
                }
              });
          }
```

Comment: Try to schedule a RepeatingCommand with a delay of 1500ms, just for the sake of experimentation. Do you get the same result, or does the pop-up show up 1500ms before the rest of the code is executed ?